# Cant get the actionDelete() to redirect properly in Yii :

Tags: php, yii, authorization, http-redirect

So here's the problem that I am facing : I have created a blog system in Yii and I have created a comments creation form in the Post view page. I have also created a delete link, and the link is working fine and the comment is indeed getting deleted when I click on the delete link, however when the comment gets deleted I am redirected to the admin Gridview for the comments page.

This is the default delete action in the Comment Controller :

```
public function actionDelete($id)
    {
        $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

        // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser

        if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
            $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));
    }
```

However, I have tried playing with the *returnUrl* as well however, I am still not able to redirect back to the same post view page that I am in. I am constantly getting redirected to the admin page of the comment management.

This is the CHtml::link that I have in the view file :

```
<?php echo CHtml::link('Delete','#',array('submit'=>array('comment/delete','id'=>$comment->id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure?')); ?>
```

This deletes the required comment fine, but I want it to be redirected to this page itself after deletion.

If any more code is required I shall give it.

P.S : Here is the accessRules for the CommentController if it would help :

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        return array(
            array('allow',  // allow all users to perform 'index' and 'view' actions
                'actions'=>array('index','view','create'),
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),

            array('allow', // allow admin user to perform 'admin' and 'delete' actions
                'actions'=>array('admin','delete','update'),
                'users'=>array('@'),
            ),
            array('deny',  // deny all users
                'users'=>array('*'),
            ),
        );
    }
```

I am sorry if I am doing something very wrong. I am indeed very new to Yii and doing my best to learn it as best as I can.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
echo CHtml::link('Delete','#',array('submit'=>array('comment/delete','id'=>$comment->id),'confirm'=>'Are you sure?')); ?
```

This line means that you create an HTML link which, when clicked, will submit in *post* mode to the 'comment/delete' action.

The documentation regarding these options is available on the Yii site : 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CHtml#clientChange-detail

Obviously, there is no 'returnUrl' argument set into $_POST here, only 'id' is set. That's why  you are always redirected to the *admin* view.

I don't know how exactly you use *urlReturn* otherwise but for the redirection, I guess the idea would be something like :

```
    public function actionDelete($id) {
    $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

    // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser
    if (!isset($_GET['ajax'])) {
        $this->redirect(Yii::app()->getRequest()->urlReferrer);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.. Yeah this worked!! :) I totally forgot about the urlReferrer!!

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the HTTP referrer

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->loadModel($id)->delete();

    // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser

    if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : array('admin'));
}
```

or derive the URL of the post from the model you're loading, and then redirect there. I don't know your exact implementation details, but it goes a little like this (assuming you have a route `blogPost/view` and the `comment` model has a relation `blogPost` to the blog post the comment is for:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $model->delete();

    // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser

    if(!isset($_GET['ajax']))
        $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('blog/view', 'id' => $model->blogPost->id));
}
```

Comment: Thank you..! I got it.. the urlReferrer method is definitely what would do the trick here. I got the answer from Herode and you!
Much regards